What crime does an accessory commit?
An arsonist committed arson. What crime does an accessory commit? I'm asking for the term describing this crime.

An accessory commits the crime of being an accessory to whatever crime the principal or main offender commits. The exact meaning, and whether there is a difference from the term 'accomplice' depends on the jurisdiction (which you have not specified).

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for a specialized legal term and would be better asked on a forum devoted to law.

An "accessory" is someone who helps someone else commit a crime. So if you murder someone by poisoning him, and I gave you the poison and told you how to use it, then I am an "accessory". The crime is "being an accessory". There's a wide range of crimes you could be assisting. Clearly being an accessory to murder is a worse crime than being an accessory to illegally parking in a handicap space.
If you want more specifics than that, you're really asking a question about law and not about English.

I voted to close the question, but I can't see anything wrong with this answer that might justify someone's downvote.
